# Can I see which of the legendary swords I picked when I completed the quest with Shaxx?

Tags: destiny

I have 3 characters in Destiny and I've just completed the mission step for the exotic sword where I had to do 500 kills with arc abilities and gather 10 rare materials from Spinmetal on earth, on my Warlock.

On my 2nd character I picked up a legendary sword as well but this character is now at the PvP step. After picking up the sword on that character, at some point I purchased the 3rd sword from Shaxx, a feature that became available with Taken King I think.

The question now is. On my 3rd character I have turned in the materials with Shaxx and I'm ready to pick the legendary sword. In order to get exotic versions of all swords I need to pick the type I purchased, so that on each character I've picked a different kind.

I can't remember which one I picked on my 2nd character and which one I bought, however.

Is my only option to complete the PvP step on my 2nd character so that I can see which kind of ability I need to use, or is there some information somewhere that shows me what I picked?

Summary:

1. My warlock picked the arc sword when he turned in materials with Shaxx
2. My titan picked either void or solar when he got to that point
3. I later then purchased either void or solar to complete the two I already had
4. Can I see somewhere now which one I picked on my 2nd character, or do I need to wait for the ability-step to see which ability I need to use?

---

To clarify for comment

1. I have all 3 legendary swords, none exotic yet
2. On my Warlock (1st character) I just now completed the step where I had to gather 10 rare spinmetal items and kill 500 mobs with Arc abilities, this is clearly for the Arc exotic sword.
3. On my Titan I am on a previous step, where I now have to kill 25 people with Sword in PvP, this is before the ability-step
4. I purchased the 3rd sword to complement the two I then had but I cannot remember which one I picked from Shaxx on my titan and which one I subsequently purchased. Either I picked Void on my titan and then purchased the solar sword, or vice versa.
5. Can I see which one I picked on my titan, or do I just have to wait until the ability-kill step to see which ability to use?

Comment: Just so I understand - you finished the quest on Warlock, but you're still working on the quest for titan and hunter? So you only have the arc sword in your kiosk?

Comment: I have not finished the exotic quest at all on any character, I clarified the question (hopefully) with an edit now.

Comment: Does Shaxx offer the ability to purchase ANY of the legendary swords now? I thought he only offered that after you completed the exotic quest

Comment: I can purchase the legendary swords on any of my 3 characters, for materials.

Comment: Hm. Let me do some digging and see if I can figure this out.

Comment: I'm currently working on the PvP step so I'll figure it out eventually but I would like to just pick up the sword on my hunter now, I guess I'll just have to wait :)

Answer (score 1):

Luckily for you, any sword kills count towards that step in the quest line. So simply go into the world and into Crucible with *any* sword currently owned and get the kills.

Following that, it is very easy to determine because of the type of element required to get kills with.

- Dark Drinker (void): void kills paired with relic iron, Mars
- Bolt Caster (arc): arc kills paired with spin metal, Earth
- Raze-Lighter (fire): fire kills paired with helium filaments, Moon

I currently have all 3 of these.

Answer (score 0):

A Sword Reforged Part 1 applies to all of your swords, and can in fact trigger A Sword Reforged Part 2 (the ability kills/material gathering quest) for all swords separately once turned in, so long as all the swords you have are above 280 Light and completely upgraded.  So, you should be able to give both swords to one character and complete ASR P1, then trigger ASR P2 for both swords.

As an aside, don't do the void sword on your titan, neither kills while inside the bubble nor kills while buffed by the bubble count as void ability kills for the quest.

Comment: I have completed the PvP now, but not turned in the quest. What do you suggest I do about it? I suspect I picked the void sword on the titan not thinking of the ability kills. I have both the solar and the void sword on him now, should I have the solar one equipped when I turn in? Should I have only that sword on him?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Make sure both swords are 280 Light and completely upgraded (they should have a yellow border around their inventory icon), and put them in the inventory of the character you want to turn in the quest on.  Once you've turned in the quest, it should trigger two quests from Shaxx, one for each sword.  I'm not sure what happens if you turn it in before you've upgraded both of them, I'd assume it just starts it for the first one you upgrade but you could try sending them to your warlock and see if it starts the quest even though your warlock already turned in part 1...

Comment: ...for a different sword

Comment: I turned in the quest on the titan with only the Sol sword on him in the hopes that this would give me the Solar quest. It did, but it also gave me the void quest. This means I will pick up the void sword on my hunter and go down the quest line again, so then I can just focus on the sol sword on my hunter and let the void be. I will keep the void quest on the titan though, on the off chance that these quests can only be gotten once each per account or something strange like that.

Comment: I picket up void on hunter, sent it to the Warlock, which is now waiting for Armsday on the exotic arc quest. I then infused the void sword to 282, upgraded it fully and talked to Shaxx. Got the quest for the exotic sword, skippet the whole part 1 quest with PvP and everything. Final results is that I can now do Arc and Void sword on my warlock and Solar (and Void) sword on my titan (though I will drop Void on titan). All in all very nice :)